# Migration: Magento CE 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.2.0 CE

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, data-migration

Migration process breaks due to below error:

> [system.db.CDbCommand] `CDbCommand::fetchAll()` failed: SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.catalog_product_website'
>   doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: `` SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `catalog_product_website` ``. 2018/05/03 17:02:26 [error]
>   [exception.CDbException] CDbException: The table
>   "{{catalog_product_website}}" for active record class
>   "Mage1CatalogProductWebsite" cannot be found in the database.

Magento version is CE 1.7.0.2 to 2.2.0 and I am using UB Data Migration Lite - 1.0.6.
When I checked in Magento 1 database table "catalog_product_website" is not exist.

What should I follow please suggest accordingly.

Comment: Magento 1 database table "catalog_product_website" is not exist??

Comment: No. Not in my Magento 1.7 database.